# Why does using router.push give me error in the console?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-router

node v16.13.2

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "3.4.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.4.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.13",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.13",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.14",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.16.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1"
  },
```

Vue component

```
<ion-card
v-for="(page, index) in pageList" :key="index"
@click="() => this.$router.push('/stock/view/' + page.id)">
```

OR

```
v-on:click="pageSelected('/stock/view/' + sel.id)"
```

```
pageSelected(route) {
    if (route) this.$router.push(route);
},
```

Without `[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler`

I get an error `vue-router.esm-bundler.js?ec2d:2489 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: api.now is not a function` when I follow a link.

If I downgrade the version I get an new errors.

Where am I wrong?

Error screenshot **:**

[image]

Tried downgrade the version npm packets, but get an new another errors.

`Update: Need to update the browser Chrome to the latest version!`

Comment: OMG, it's work in a FireFox. I am shocked by vue and ionic

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because of some new updates in Vue Router, I and my colleagues all of them resolved it by installing **new stable version of** **Vue Devtools**

Please uninstall the existing Devtool extension and download this stable version: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Comment: I cant believe this extension was the issue! Thank you so much @riyaz

Comment: In my case I have updated the vue-router version from 4.0.0-0 to 4.1.5 and it works like a charm. As I already had a stable version of Devtool extension.

Answer (score 0):

`If you get api.now() error, you can switch to 4.0.13`
https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/1338#issuecomment-1065886174

You can share your code on https://codesandbox.io/ or https://stackblitz.com/.

This will allow others to help you better

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. But! I updated the Chrome version from the previous one to the latest one and everything worked! I'm crying with joy)) My rating does not allow you to evaluate the answer(